# How to have a variable number of structures without vector and without an array of structures in c?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, structure

For more detail, I need to create a program that reads a name, address, city/state, and zip code from input and puts them into a structure that holds all of this information, e.g.

```
   struct person
   {
     char name[100];
     char address[100];
     char citystate[100];
     char zipcode[5];
   }
```

I need my program to work for ANY amount of inputs from the user. If the user enters the information for 500 people, it needs to create 500 structures, if they enter 1000 sets of information I need 1000 structures (struct person variables?), etc.

The catch is that I may NOT use an array of structures, so I can't simply malloc an array of structures to hold any amount of information...

How do I accomplish what is required?

Furthermore, as a side question, once I read in and store the information, I need an array of pointers to point to each structure so I can sort the in a function more efficiently than by passing the entire structures. I imagine this would be accomplished by creating a dynamic array of pointers, but I was advised to use a statically declared one, why is this?

Apologies if this question isn't specific enough, if any more detail is required please mention so and I'll add what I can.

Comment: If this is a homework question, it's a terrible one. You're being asked to solve a standard problem without being able to use a standard solution.

Comment: No vector, huh? Be a jerk and use a std::list. Better still, std::set. It sorts for you. If you can't use any stl containers... take a read of [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Comment: What have you just been learning about in class? Chances are they want you to use that.

Comment: *"Apologies if this question isn't specific enough, if any more detail is required please mention so and I'll add what I can."* - so, can you use `std::list<>`?  You're not making any effort to provide details or comment on answers, and the question remains too broad as you haven't stipulated how constrained you are re the Standard Library in general.

Comment: @TonyD Sorry for the delayed response to the answer(s) here. No, I cannot use std::list<> . I am required to use an array of pointers to a structure to sort the information by zip code. The problem I'm having now is understanding how to write this.

Comment: Well, saying *"an array of pointers to structures is mandated"* would have led to more useful help than your *"may NOT use an array of structures"*, as if the difference between those is so slight that the answers have jumped even further from arrays to look at other container types.  Sounds like you're best off implementing a bare-bones "vector"-like container in which you can store the pointers.  Have you learnt any Object Oriented programming yet - `class`, member variables and functions?  `new[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: @TonyD We have not learnt vectors, so I'm unfamiliar with how I would write anything as vector-like. Have not learnt any object-oriented programming yet. Evidently, I should create the array of pointers to the structure and then malloc to dynamically allocate memory for each index. The problem now is the syntax. Would something like this work?:


`int i;
struct person *P[100];

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   P[i] = (struct person *)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
   
`

Comment: Given *"to work for ANY amount of inputs"*, having a fixed-sized array seems to defeat the purpose.  Also, in C++ it's best to use `new[]` and `delete[]` rather than `malloc()`, as they invoke constructors and destructors for you if necessary - one less place to fix the code if you add such functions to your `person` class.

Comment: I suggest you use something like `int capacity = 10; person* p_persons= new person[capacity]; int num_persons = 0;` to start with, then each time you add a person you can say `if (num_persons + 1 == capacity) { person* p = new person[capacity *= 2]; std::copy(p_persons, p_persons + num_persons, p); delete[] p_persons; p_persons = p; } p_persons[++num_persons] = new_person;`. What that does is start with space for 10 people, and each time you run out of space allocate twice as much, copy person data over, then release the old memory and start using the new.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you would want to do:

```
struct person
{
  std::string name;
  std::string address;
  std::string citystate;
  char zipcode[5];
};

std::vector<person> people;
```

That is the way to do a container of an unknown number of one type that is easily iterable. You can take full advantage of the [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to do all of your sorting, searching, etc. To quote Alex Stepanov, the original creator of STL:

> Use vectors whenever you can. If you cannot use vectors, redesign your solution so that you can use vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditinos of your assignment forbid vectors and arrays, you're forced to some potentially less-suitable data structure, such as a linked list.  If you're not required to write your own, use [`std::list<person>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).  When it comes time to sort, call the [`list`'s `sort` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort): you can use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to control the sort order if necessary, or write an `bool operator<(const person& lhs, const person& rhs)` function to give `person` an ordering that the `list` will pick up by default.